# awk | Not able to merge 2 files

Tags: awk, gawk

I am new to awk and trying to write code which can merge 2 files..

File1

```
session=123;1,code=01,name=om  
session=345;3,code=04,name=ra
```

File2

```
time=44,minute=22,sec=01,session=123;1,creation=89
time=34,minute=12,sec=023,session=523;1,creation=80
```

Output should be

```
time=44,minute=22,sec=01,session=123;1,creation=89,code=01,name=om
time=34,minute=12,sec=023,session=523;1,creation=80,,
```

I have written something like:

```
BEGIN { FS = OFS = "," }
FNR == NR {
  a[$2] = substr($0,index($0,$2));
  next
}
{
  if($4 in a)print $0","a[$2];
  else print $0",,";
}
```

But this does not generate the correct output.

Could you please help where I was mistaken?

Comment: Why isn't the rest of the line of `file1` included in the expected output? Are there really supposed to be multiple `session` values on the same line in `file1`?

Comment: Because file2 is Base file.. if something extra in file1 then that can be ignored.. but I need everything from file2.

Comment: My question was due to the incorrect formatting of `file1` before you edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`index($0, $2)` is not a good way to get everything after field 2. In the first line of `file1`, `$2` is `"1"`, so `index($0, "1")` finds the `1` in `section=123`.

Try this:

```
BEGIN { FS = OFS = "," }
FNR == NR {
  session=$1;
  $1 = "";
  a[session] = $0;
  next
}
{
  if($4 in a)print $0","a[$4];
  else print $0",,";
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. but Why substr($0,index($0,$2)) is not working.. In this example I have only 3 and 4 fields.. there can be n number of fields.. then substr is better.. right? or please suggest your views

Comment: I am still not getting merge output .. # awk -f field_merge_2_1.awk file1.log file2.log
time=44,minute=22,sec=01,session=123;1,creation=89,,
time=34,minute=12,sec=023,session=523;1,creation=80,,

Comment: When `$22` is `1`, `index($0, $2)` is the position of the first `1` in the line, not the position of field 3.

Comment: You were referring to the wrong field in `file1`, the field you should have been using as the array index was `$1`. I've updated the answer to store everything after field 1 into the array.

Comment: I dont know but I am getting syntax error.. Is this version issue with awk?awk -f field_merge_2_1.awk file1.log file2.log
awk: field_merge_2_1.awk:4:   $1 = '';
awk: field_merge_2_1.awk:4:        ^ invalid char ''' in expression

Comment: Still not the desired output.. time=44,minute=22,sec=01,session=123;1,creation=89,
time=34,minute=12,sec=023,session=523;1,creation=80,,
Do we need to use a[$2] in awk or a[session]?

Comment: It should be `a[$4]`, not `a[$2]`.

Comment: Perfect.. now it works :) Just for my understanding .. why we have cleared $1 with $1 = ""; ?

Comment: Clearing `$1` removes that field from `$0`, so you can then put `$0` in the array to get the rest of the line.